# Student Management System C++

Tags: c++

I have this program in C++ for Student Management System , Everything is working fine , except one place where i try to delete a student based on his roll number . 
What it should do : After asking the roll number search the record and delete it
What is it doing : It deletes all the other records which do not match that roll number

Here is my code :

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <cstdio>

    #include <cstring>

    #include <cstdlib>

    #include <conio.h>

    #include <iomanip>



using namespace std;
int main() {

    FILE *fp, *ft;

    char another, choice;



struct student {

        char first_name[50], last_name[50];
        int roll_num; //new code added
        char course[100];
        int section;
    };

    struct student e;
    char xfirst_name[50], xlast_name[50];
    int xroll_num ; // new code added
    long int recsize;

    fp=fopen("users.txt","rb+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("users.txt","wb+");

        if (fp==NULL)
        {
             puts("Cannot open file");
             return 0;
        }
    }


 recsize = sizeof(e);

 while(1) {
     system("cls");

     cout << "\t\t====== STUDENT INFORMATION SYSTEM ======";
     cout <<"\n\n                                          ";
     cout << "\n\n";
     cout<<" \n\t\t\t======================";
     cout << "\n \t\t\t  1. Add    Records";
     cout << "\n \t\t\t  2. List   Records";
     cout << "\n \t\t\t  3. Modify Records";
     cout << "\n \t\t\t  4. Delete Records";
     cout << "\n \t\t\t  5. Exit   Program";
     cout<<" \n\t\t\t======================";
     cout << "\n\n";
     cout << "\t\t\t Select Your Choice ::";
     fflush(stdin);
     choice = _getche();
     switch(choice)
     {
      case '1' :
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
            another ='Y';
            while(another == 'Y' || another == 'y')
            {
                  system("cls");
                cout << "Enter the First Name : ";
                cin >> e.first_name;
                cout << "Enter the Last Name : ";
                cin >> e.last_name;
                cout << "Enter the Course    : ";
                cin >> e.course;
                cout << "Enter the Section   : ";
                cin >> e.section;
                cout << "Enter the roll number :";
                cin >> e.roll_num;
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fp);
                cout << "\n Add Another Record (Y/N) ";
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getchar();
            }
            break;
      case '2':
            system("cls");
           rewind(fp);
           cout << "=== View the Records in the Database ===";
           cout << "\n";
           while (fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1){
           cout << "\n";
           cout <<"\nName     :: " <<e.first_name <<" "<<e.last_name;
           //cout << "\n";
           cout <<"\nRoll Number :: " << e.roll_num ;
           cout <<"\nCourse   :: " <<e.course ;
           cout <<"\nSection  :: "<<e.section;
           }
           cout << "\n\n";
           system("pause");
           break;

       case '3' :
            system("cls");
          another = 'Y';
          while (another == 'Y'|| another == 'y')
          {
         //     cout << "\n Enter the last name of the student : ";
              cout << "\n Enter the Roll number of the student : ";
              cin >> xroll_num;

            rewind(fp);
            while (fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1)
            {
                //if (strcmp(e.last_name,xlast_name) == 0)
                if(e.roll_num == xroll_num )
                {
                cout << "Enter the new Firt Name : ";
                cin >> e.first_name;
                cout << "Enter the new Last Name : ";
                cin >> e.last_name;
                cout << "Enter the new Roll Number : ";
                cin >> e.roll_num;
                cout << "Enter the new Course    : ";
                cin >> e.course;
                cout << "Enter the new Section   : ";
                cin >> e.section;
                fseek(fp, - recsize, SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fp);
                break;
                }
                else
                cout<<"record not found";
            }
            cout << "\n Modify Another Record (Y/N) ";
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getchar();
            }
            break;


         case '4':
       system("cls");
           another = 'Y';
          while (another == 'Y'|| another == 'y')
          {
           //   cout << "\n Enter the last name of the student to delete : ";
              cout <<"\n Enter the roll number of the student to delete : ";
              cin >> xroll_num;

              ft = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");

              rewind(fp);
              while (fread (&e, recsize,1,fp) == 1)

                // if (strcmp(e.last_name,xlast_name) != 0)
                    if(e.roll_num == xroll_num )
                {
                    fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ft);
                }
                fclose(fp);
                fclose(ft);
                remove("users.txt");
                rename("temp.dat","users.txt");

                fp=fopen("users.txt","rb+");

                cout << "\n Delete Another Record (Y/N) ";
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getchar();
              }

              break;

              case '5':
              fclose(fp);
              cout << "\n\n";
              cout << "\t\t     THANK YOU FOR USING THIS SOFTWARE";
              cout << "\n\n";
              exit(0);
          }
          }
     system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you print on the console, the value of "e.roll_num"

Comment: Any specific reason you are calling this C++ (but for `cout`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It deletes all the other records which do not match that roll number

Well you're only writing the records that match the roll number to the temp file, and then using that file to overwrite the `users.txt` file

```
if (e.roll_num == xroll_num) {
  fwrite(&e, recsize, 1, ft);
}
```

I suppose what you really wanted to do is

```
if (e.roll_num != xroll_num) {
  fwrite(&e, recsize, 1, ft);
}
```

You should probably read a good C++ i/o tutorial, as your code is mostly C. Consider writing your `student` struct as simple text instead of writing it wholesale to the file.

Comment: can you suggest me any tutorial where i can instead save all values to a proper excel file in row -column order or something ?

Comment: @user3562802 csv files are quite straightforward to create and can be opened in excel.